# Python Pandas conditional flagging

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

Working with python pandas dataframe df:

```
product_id |transaction_id | category | color
234          54              A           black
349          54              B           silver
213          46              A           silver
490          46              A           black
245          87              A           black
249          87              B           black
294          87              A           silver
```

I want to flag transaction_IDs that have category of A and B with the same color. So in the scenario above transaction 87 has a product A black and a product B black.

Desired output:

```
product_id |transaction_id | category | color  | flag
234          54              A           black
349          54              B           silver
213          46              A           silver
490          46              A           black
245          87              A           black    X
249          87              B           black    X
294          87              A           silver   X
```

I was trying to create a unique key between category and color and then groupby, but it got messy and I still have to go manually through it. There must be a simpler way.

```
df['key']=df['category']&df['color']

df['transaction_analysis']= df.groupby('transaction_id').key.transform(lambda x : '&'.join(set(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if simpler, but certainly cleaner. You may `groupby` on `transaction_id` and `category`, find unique colours with `unique`, and then unstack.

After this, generate a mapping of flag values and assign to `df` later.

```
v = (
    df.groupby(['transaction_id', 'category'])
      .color
      .unique()
      .unstack(fill_value=set())
)
m = {
  k : 'X' if set(x).intersection(y) else '' for k, x, y in zip(v.index, v.A, v.B)
}    
df['flag'] = df['transaction_id'].map(m)
```

```
df

   product_id  transaction_id category   color flag
0         234              54        A   black     
1         349              54        B  silver     
2         213              46        A  silver     
3         490              46        A   black     
4         245              87        A   black    X
5         249              87        B   black    X
6         294              87        A  silver    X
```

Comment: uhhh! let me try this, it's similar logic to mine, but I agree it's cleaner by far

Comment: would you mind explaining this in more detail k : 'X' if set(x).intersection(y) else '' for k, x, y in zip(v.index, v.A, v.B)? I would like to be able to do similar logic in the future alone without bothering users on stackoverflow

Comment: @jeangelj from the first line you get two columns, one for each category, and the index is the txn_id. Now I want to find what categories have colours in common by using set.intersection. I use this to flag the txn_ids. After that it's as straightforward as mapping those flags back to the original using pd.Series.map.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'color': ['black', 'silver', 'silver', 'black', 
                             'black', 'black', 'silver'],
                   'product_id': [234, 349, 213, 490, 245, 249, 294],
                   'transaction_id': [54, 54, 46, 46, 87, 87, 87]})

pivoted = df.pivot_table(index=['transaction_id','color'], columns=['category'], 
                         values='product_id')
transaction_color_mask = pd.notnull(pivoted).all(axis=1)
transaction_map = transaction_color_mask.groupby(level=0).any().map({True:'X',False:''})
df['flag'] = df['transaction_id'].map(transaction_map)
print(df)
```

yields

```
  category   color  product_id  transaction_id flag
0        A   black         234              54     
1        B  silver         349              54     
2        A  silver         213              46     
3        A   black         490              46     
4        A   black         245              87    X
5        B   black         249              87    X
6        A  silver         294              87    X
```

---

The main idea is to use `pivot_table` to expose the values-to-be-compared in rows:

```
In [182]: pivoted
Out[182]: 
category                   A      B
transaction_id color               
46             black   490.0    NaN
               silver  213.0    NaN
54             black   234.0    NaN
               silver    NaN  349.0
87             black   245.0  249.0
               silver  294.0    NaN
```

Now we can find rows whose categories `A` and `B` have the same color:

```
In [183]: transaction_color_mask = pd.notnull(pivoted).all(axis=1); transaction_color_mask
Out[183]: 
transaction_id  color 
46              black     False
                silver    False
54              black     False
                silver    False
87              black      True
                silver    False
dtype: bool
```

Group by `transaction_id` to find `transaction_id`s associated with True rows:

```
In [184]: transaction_color_mask.groupby(level=0).any()
Out[184]: 
transaction_id
46    False
54    False
87     True
dtype: bool
```

then map `True` to `'X'` and `False` to empty strings:

```
In [185]: transaction_color_mask.groupby(level=0).any().map({True:'X',False:''})
Out[185]: 
transaction_id
46     
54     
87    X
dtype: object
```

Finally, recombine the result with `df`: `df['flag'] = df['transaction_id'].map(transaction_map)` yields the desired result.

Comment: wow! thank you so much, I can see the effort put into this answer, let me try